# Is it possible to skip Skyrim's new game introduction cinematic?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I don't want to watch the prisoner cart ride to the execution: is it possible to skip this?

If so, how? Can I replace the intro movie file by some empty video?

Comment: It's not a movie...it's actually rendered real-time.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The game automatically saves the game just before the Imperials start reading off names.

Once you've played through the intro once (and assuming you haven't turned off Auto-Save) you can always load that game: It should list your name as "Prisoner", your Race as "Nord" and your level as "1". (And is likely save 001).

Comment: @Arkive - It hasn't gotten overwritten in my game, and I've not touched the auto-save settings. (This is PC for what it's worth)

Comment: @Arkive a regular save (hence the number instead of "AUTO" or "QUICK")

Comment: Oh that makes sense...

Comment: Played through it again. The game creates a regular save. I guess I just saved over my 001 save.  I'll delete my earlier comment to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 16):

A savegame right after the introduction can be found [at the Skyrim Nexus](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/17/?)

Comment: An excellent resource for those foolish enough to overwrite their save games.  \*sigh\*

Answer (score 7):

If playing on the PC or Xbox One, installing the [**Alternate Start - Live Another Life** (PC)](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/9557/?) / [(Xbox One)](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim/mod-detail/2918744) mod will allow you to skip the game introduction cinematic at Helgen. It will offer a choice of which location you want to start in (you can start the game in Dawnstar, for example).

> Live Another Life provides an alternative means to start the game for those who do not wish to go through the lengthy intro sequence at Helgen. You will be given the opportunity to choose your race and then choose a new life for your character to lead. A wide variety of choices will be available...

Comment: This is also available for the XBox One:  https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim/mod-detail/2918744

Comment: @ReginaldBlue Thanks. Added that info to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The minute they start taking names and by the time Hadvar says 'who are you', quickly save the game and you will instantly go to the character creator menu